# How to keep the currency symbol in the right position from free text?

Tags: javascript, currency

Suppose I have the function presented below to extract prices from free text. Where prices sometimes have the currency symbol in a different position, for example, "19€99". How could I rewrite or change the way this algorithm works to accommodate this new requirement and future such requirements?

```
var valid_countries = ["US", "IT"]

function extractPrice(description, country){

  if (!valid_countries.includes(country)){
    return -1
  }

  if (country == "US") {
    var price = description.match(/\$(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]

    if (price == null) {
      return -1
    }

    return parsreFloat(price)
  }

  if (country == "IT") {
    var price = description.match(/\€(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]

    if (price == null) {
      return -1
    }

    return parsreFloat(price)
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this for all currencies. This is working well in crawling websites. Also easily read, modify and can be improved in my opinion. You can add your `extractPrice` function and return with `formPrice`.

```js
let priceTexts = [
    "19€99",
    "19,99€",
    "19.99€",
    "19,€99",
    "19$99",
    "19,99$",
    "19.99$",
    "19,$99",
    "€19.99",
    "$19.99",
    "CHF 19.99",
    "19,99 TL",
    "19tl.99"
]

function formPrice(value) {
    return parseFloat(value.replace(/[$€A-Za-z]/g, " ").trim().replace(/\s/g, ".").replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, ".").replace(/\.+/g, "."))
}

function formPriceWithSymbol(value) {
    let symbol = value.replace(/[^$€A-Za-z]/g, "").toUpperCase()
    return symbol + value.replace(/[$€A-Za-z]/g, " ").trim().replace(/\s/g, ".").replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, ".").replace(/\.+/g, ".")
}

let prices = priceTexts.map((price) => {
    return formPrice(price)
})

console.log(prices)

prices = priceTexts.map((price) => {
    return formPriceWithSymbol(price)
})

console.log(prices)
```

Comment: But you trim the currency symbol. I want to keep the currency symbol to the left side.

Comment: I edited my answer, but idk, if symbols stay in the string you can't parse the string to float?